# React Native - trigger scrolling of FlatList outside the FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have a vertical `FlatList` component and two buttons as `TouchableOpacity`, how do I perform scrolling of the `FlatList` with the buttons,

i.e. 'scrolling the FlatList towards bottom` and 'scroll the FlatList towards top'?

Minimal Example:

```
<View>
    <FlatList/>
    <TouchableOpacity>
        <Text>Scroll towards Top</>Text
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity>
        <Text>Scroll towards Bottom</>Text
    </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

Comment: Andus, check if my answer can help you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not difficult to accomplish, The `<Flatlist/>` component already have methods to do that.

- [`scrollToEnd()`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#scrolltoend): Scrolls to the end of the content.
- [`scrollToIndex()`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#scrolltoindex): Scrolls to the item at the specified index such `0` which is the top.

I have created a simple demo for you: https://snack.expo.io/@abranhe/flatlist-scroll

I have created a custom `<Button/>` and `<Card/>` components. I am creating an array with some random data with this format

```js
const data = [
 { message: 'Random Message' },  { message: 'Random Message' }
]
```

I am adding a reference to the `<Flatlist/>` by adding

```js
ref={ref => (this.flatlist = ref)}
```

Then I call the methods and that's it.

```js
<Button title="▼" onPress={() => this.flatlist.scrollToEnd()} />
```

[image]

The whole source code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, FlatList, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { random } from 'merry-christmas';
import Card from './components/Card';
import Button from './components/Button';

const data = [...Array(10)].map(i => ({ message: random() }));

export default () => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <FlatList
      ref={ref => (this.flatlist = ref)}
      data={data}
      renderItem={({ item }) => <Card gretting={item.message} />}
    />
    <View style={styles.bottomContainer}>
      <Button
        title="▲"
        onPress={() => this.flatlist.scrollToIndex({ index: 0 })}
      />
      <Button title="▼" onPress={() => this.flatlist.scrollToEnd()} />
    </View>
  </View>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a scrollView component

Comment: I need to use a flatlist component instead of a scrollview because of performance.

Comment: Yeah i understand,instead of closing them under a view tag, close them under a scrollViewTag, the performance would still be good, since the flatlist is covering the one with large data

Comment: Maybe I should clarify my question, normally you use your finger to trigger the scroll of flatlist by swiping it, I want to replace the swiping action by button clicks, which the buttons are outside the flatlist

Comment: Ohhh i understand now, you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51629192/react-native-horizontal-scroll-on-button-click)