# react-native FlastList cannot scroll to the end

Tags: react-native

I want to implement a chat room that use the FlastList to load chat logs, so I need the FlastList to scroll to the bottom of the list every time I have a new chat log. But it didn't work

"react": "16.8.3",
"react-native": "^0.58.6",

```
    this.refs.flatlist.scrollToEnd()
```

Comment: How doesn't working?

Comment: Try this `this.refs.flatlist.current.scrollToEnd()`

Comment: Also make sure by doing `console.log(this.refs.flatlist.current)` that it contains `scrollToEnd()` method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native - trigger scrolling of FlatList outside the FlatList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57397669/react-native-trigger-scrolling-of-flatlist-outside-the-flatlist)